# how to move files from subfolders to another location with same folder names

Tags: move

I have to move .CIDRDUP to another location with same folder names and subfolders also
For Example i have a files in this location "E:\Cidr\19-1-2015\2017\packets"
have to move to this location "H:\Cidr\19-1-2015\2017\packets" with CMD Plzz Help Me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I asume you are on on Windows (7 / 8) machine, in this case use robocopy:

`robocopy E:\Cidr\19-1-2015\2017\packets H:\Cidr\19-1-2015\2017\packets /E`

You can get more information on the syntax using `robocopy /?` in cmd

e.g. if you really want to move the files add `/move`

You could also use the `move` command for syntax use `help move`

And instead of asking such a trivial question here, you could have simply searched for the answer on the internet.

Comment: Dear Maximilian i have thousands of files different formats  in source  folder. Have to move one single format ( .CIDRDUP ) files only.

Comment: /E takes care that all files and subfolders are also copylied. If you also use /move you will also move files